# How to get in-app or subscription info from server side?

Tags: ios, server, in-app-purchase, itunes

Is it possbile to get In-app (or subscription) information (at least price, currency) for iOS application by `bundle id` or `product id` from server side?

I know that iOS clients possible to do it using their SDK.

Maybe exists service like iTunes Lookup API?

Comment: Other than`SKProductsRequest`?

Comment: @BenFlynn, yes. I plan to do it on server side via php.

Answer (score 0):

In StoreKit you  have SKProduct and there you have the price
You can check it here 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/

Comment: I want get this data throw api (by http(s)) from web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no, they intend you to fetch the IAPs from within the app. Here is an example of what is returned from the iTunes affiliate search API. AFAIK there is no other API to query app information. They don't mention other ways in their [guide to obtaining IAP information](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html).

```
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=828578246

{
  "resultCount": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "isGameCenterEnabled": true,
      "screenshotUrls": [
        "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple49/v4/67/01/ff/6701ff5c-55d3-0ea6-d868-8d803072483b/screen696x696.jpeg",
        "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/7c/14/5f/7c145fc0-d7af-cfce-eede-f35ad50a779e/screen696x696.jpeg",
        "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/cc/0a/43/cc0a4393-a006-f485-a4b5-59049b16da18/screen696x696.jpeg",
        "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/e1/76/23/e1762373-849f-9935-7880-34b62365db8c/screen696x696.jpeg",
        "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/84/2f/63/842f635e-ccb1-7802-3fc3-020024a8d786/screen696x696.jpeg"
      ],
      "ipadScreenshotUrls": [
        "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/26/ea/ca/26eacabe-8606-de7e-c49a-aeb961c44a22/sc1024x768.jpeg",
        "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple49/v4/11/60/5a/11605ad9-c93a-92d2-2abf-faff83c7e5e4/sc1024x768.jpeg",
        "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/bb/b5/8e/bbb58e8a-f6fb-7a4d-e6b9-02ad3007d601/sc1024x768.jpeg",
        "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/82/d5/34/82d53417-01aa-e6eb-f0f6-c57e76dae3d9/sc1024x768.jpeg",
        "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple49/v4/04/ad/f4/04adf415-1a40-58b6-6d82-6e47394668e4/sc1024x768.jpeg"
      ],
      "appletvScreenshotUrls": [],
      "artworkUrl60": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/14/68/e7/1468e7e9-9dc8-4493-2738-bba066cd03c4/source/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl512": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/14/68/e7/1468e7e9-9dc8-4493-2738-bba066cd03c4/source/512x512bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/14/68/e7/1468e7e9-9dc8-4493-2738-bba066cd03c4/source/100x100bb.jpg",
      "artistViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/big-fish-games-inc/id292594310?uo=4",
      "kind": "software",
      "features": [
        "gameCenter",
        "iosUniversal"
      ],
      "supportedDevices": [
        "iPhone4",
        "iPad2Wifi",
        "iPad23G",
        "iPhone4S",
        "iPadThirdGen",
        "iPadThirdGen4G",
        "iPhone5",
        "iPodTouchFifthGen",
        "iPadFourthGen",
        "iPadFourthGen4G",
        "iPadMini",
        "iPadMini4G",
        "iPhone5c",
        "iPhone5s",
        "iPhone6",
        "iPhone6Plus",
        "iPodTouchSixthGen"
      ],
      "advisories": [],
      "trackCensoredName": "Gummy Drop!",
      "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion": 325,
      "sellerUrl": "http://www.bigfishgames.com/mobile-games/ios-games/",
      "contentAdvisoryRating": "4+",
      "languageCodesISO2A": [
        "NL",
        "EN",
        "FR",
        "DE",
        "IT",
        "JA",
        "KO",
        "PT",
        "RU",
        "ES"
      ],
      "fileSizeBytes": "89165452",
      "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion": 4.5,
      "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gummy-drop!/id828578246?mt=8&uo=4",
      "trackContentRating": "4+",
      "minimumOsVersion": "7.0",
      "formattedPrice": "Free",
      "currency": "USD",
      "wrapperType": "software",
      "version": "2.14.0",
      "artistId": 292594310,
      "artistName": "Big Fish Games, Inc",
      "genres": [
        "Games",
        "Arcade",
        "Puzzle",
        "Entertainment"
      ],
      "price": 0,
      "description": "Stop crushing & start squishing! Match your way around this candy world! LET’S GO GUMMY! ®\n\nTravel WHEREVER and WHENEVER you want!  From Sydney to Tokyo, San Francisco, New York City, Paris, London, Rome, Berlin, New Orleans, Barcelona, Shanghai, Los Angeles, Seoul, Havana, Rio de Janeiro, St. Petersburg, Mexico City, Cape Town, Budapest, Tahiti, Cairo, Marrakesh, Dubai, Bangkok, Athens, Amsterdam, Hawaii, Hong Kong, Singapore, New Delhi, Venice and more coming soon!\n\nFEATURES\n• Play over 10,000 gummified levels across dozens of world cities – MORE levels than any other Match-3 game!\n• Travel to any city, anytime!  Earn travel vouchers to unlock the city of your choice.\n• Exciting Achievements!  See your accomplishments in your Passport.\n• Unique boosts!  Including Shuffle, Lightning, Shovel, and more!\n• Huge rewards!  Score in-game items just for playing.\n• Daily Events!  Collect sweet bursts of resources and rewards.\n\nREVIEWS\nBetter than Candy Crush (5 STARS)\nLove the way the game travels around the world.\n\nFinally a Straight Up Game Experience (5 STARS)\nThis is an amazing game that is what it says - FREE. You can keep playing a challenging de-stressor without any bait and switch. Love It!!!!!!!!\n\nFun game (5 STARS)\nThis game starts easily and increases in difficulty as you get better. Fun to watch the cities grow as you add details.\n\nCan’t get enough of Gummy Drop! ? Visit our Headquarters, like us on Facebook of follow us on Twitter for sweet musings, matching tips, gummy stories, and tasty giveaways!\n\nGummy Drop! Headquarters:  www.bigfishgames.com/gummyHQ \nFacebook: Search Gummy Drop \nTwitter: @GummyDrop  \n \n*Note for updates - having trouble seeing your progress after an update? Try connecting with Facebook again and that should do the trick!*",
      "trackName": "Gummy Drop!",
      "trackId": 828578246,
      "bundleId": "com.bigfishgames.worldsagaaapluniversalF2P",
      "releaseDate": "2014-09-08T19:29:51Z",
      "primaryGenreName": "Games",
      "isVppDeviceBasedLicensingEnabled": true,
      "currentVersionReleaseDate": "2016-08-23T17:26:54Z",
      "releaseNotes": "Join us in the newest city, Queenstown!\nPlay over 360 brand new levels of Gummy matching fun today!\n\nOther improvements:\n•Optimizations and bug fixes to improve overall game performance.\n\nThanks for the continued support and feedback, and be sure to keep an eye out for more exciting updates!\n\nExperiencing issues? Please visit http://bigfi.sh/GummyHQ",
      "sellerName": "Big Fish Games, Inc",
      "primaryGenreId": 6014,
      "genreIds": [
        "6014",
        "7003",
        "7012",
        "6016"
      ],
      "averageUserRating": 4.5,
      "userRatingCount": 46621
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for your answer. I'll try to find third-party services which able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a third-party service which allows do this.
**Appfigures**. In [docs](http://docs.appfigures.com/products) they have the type of product **inapp**. Service may return **price** and **currency**. It looks like that I need.

But need to check it in practice.

If somebody know other service which possible to do that, please, share them. Thanks!